# NSArray to C array

Tags: cocoa, opengl

Can we convert an NSArray to a C array?

If not what alternatives, are there? Suppose I need to feed the C array to OpenGL functions where the C array contains vertex pointers read from plist files.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The answer depends on the nature of the C-array.

If you need to populate an array of primitive values and of known length, you could do something like this:

```
NSArray* nsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                                             nil];
int cArray[2];

// Fill C-array with ints
int count = [nsArray count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    cArray[i] = [[nsArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}

// Do stuff with the C-array
NSLog(@"%d %d", cArray[0], cArray[1]);
```

Here's an example where we want to create a new C-array from an `NSArray`, keeping the array items as Obj-C objects:

```
NSArray* nsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", nil];

// Make a C-array
int count = [nsArray count];
NSString** cArray = malloc(sizeof(NSString*) * count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    cArray[i] = [nsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [cArray[i] retain];    // C-arrays don't automatically retain contents
}

// Do stuff with the C-array
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    NSLog(cArray[i]);
}

// Free the C-array's memory
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    [cArray[i] release];
}
free(cArray);
```

Or, you might want to `nil`-terminate the array instead of passing its length around:

```
// Make a nil-terminated C-array
int count = [nsArray count];
NSString** cArray = malloc(sizeof(NSString*) * (count + 1));

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    cArray[i] = [nsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [cArray[i] retain];    // C-arrays don't automatically retain contents
}

cArray[count] = nil;

// Do stuff with the C-array
for (NSString** item = cArray; *item; ++item) {
    NSLog(*item);
}

// Free the C-array's memory
for (NSString** item = cArray; *item; ++item) {
    [*item release];
}
free(cArray);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I wish I could up vote more than once. I do have one suggestion which is that the use of the `NSString**` type is a bit obfuscated. I suggest using `[NSData initWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:]` with the pointer that malloc returns, and the size of the array.

Comment: I tried the second approach that uses malloc, I think it requires arc to be disabled. At least, that is how I got it to work. Maybe arc did not exist when this question was asked....

Answer (score 6):

`NSArray` has a `-getObjects:range:` method for creating a C-array for a subrange of an array.

Example:

```
NSArray *someArray = /* .... */;
NSRange copyRange = NSMakeRange(0, [someArray count]);
id *cArray = malloc(sizeof(id *) * copyRange.length);

[someArray getObjects:cArray range:copyRange];

/* use cArray somewhere */

free(cArray);
```

Comment: That won't convert the NSNumber objects to a primitive numeric type, though. The questioner needs that conversion to use the C array with OpenGL; because of that, they might as well populate the C array entirely themselves, without ever putting NSNumbers into it.

Comment: ahhh! Didn't see the OpenGL requirement for the problem. In that case yes, iterating the array manually would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to convert yourself, with something like:

```
NSArray * myArray;

... // code feeding myArray

id table[ [myArray count] ];

int i = 0;
for (id item in myArray)
{
    table[i++] = item;
}
```