# How to make an C vector or array from an NSArray?

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays, vector, nsarray

Is that possible? I've seen no method that would generate a plain old C vector or array. I have just NSNumber objects in my array which I need as C vector or array.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011711/nsarray-to-c-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to mouviciel's answer is to use NSArray's [`getObjects:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBGGHJ) method.

```
id cArray[10];
NSArray *nsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2" ... @"10", nil];

[nsArray getObjects:cArray range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
```

Or, if you don't know how many objects are in the array at compile-time:

```
NSUInteger itemCount = [nsArray count];
id *cArray = malloc(itemCount * sizeof(id));

[nsArray getObjects:cArray range:NSMakeRange(0, itemCount)];

... do work with cArray ...

free(cArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need your C array to carry objects, you can declare it as :

```
id cArray[ ARRAY_COUNT ];
```

or

```
id * cArray = malloc(sizeof(id)*[array count]);
```

Then you can populate it using a loop:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<[array count] ; i++)
    cArray[i] = [array objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: The objects should be retained as they are put in the c array (i.e., [cArray[i] retain]) because the NSArray could be released thereby releasing all of the objects it contains.

Comment: Using `getObjects:range:` would be quicker.