# Passing NSArray to a cpp function

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, c++

I need to call a cpp function like

```
void myFunc(float **array2D, int rows, int cols)
{
}
```

within an objective-c object. Basically, the array is created in my objective-c code as I create an NSArray object. Now, the problem is how to pass this array to my cpp function.

I am a bit new to these mixed c++/objective-c stuffs so any hint will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The answers so far assume `array2D` is unidimensional. Can you confirm that? I’m guessing it’s a bidimensional array since the parameter is `float **array2D`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: if you are using c++, why not using std::vector's ? you would not need to send the side of the matrix. `void myFunc(std::vector<std::vector<float> > array2D){...code...}`

Comment: my array is bidimensional but it doesnt matter here as I am trying to convert NSArray of NSArray to float **. Still the objective is to convert NSArray -> float *

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have to convert the `NSArray` to a plain C array.
Something like:

```
NSArray *myNSArray; // your NSArray

int count = [myNSArray count];
float *array = new float[count];
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    array[i] = [[myNSArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
}
```

or, as a commenter suggested (assuming your `NSArray` contains `NSNumber`s):

```
NSArray *myNSArray; // your NSArray

int count = [myNSArray count];
float *array = new float[count];
int i = 0;
for(NSNumber *number in myNSArray) {
    array[i++] = [number floatValue];
}
```

Comment: instead of the `for` statement, I would use `for (NSString *element in array) {... code ...}`. using an enumeration is faster, and you save a few variable declaration. but your answer is good :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011711/nsarray-to-c-array).

Check out the answer that mentions using [NSArray getObjects] to create a c-style array.

Here's the code that the [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4556/ashley-clark) put in there:

```
NSArray *someArray = /* .... */;
NSRange copyRange = NSMakeRange(0, [someArray count]);
id *cArray = malloc(sizeof(id *) * copyRange.length);

[someArray getObjects:cArray range:copyRange];

/* use cArray somewhere */

free(cArray);
```

Comment: But OP’s function expects an array of `float`, so this method is not really applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, since CFArray is toll-free bridged to NSArray, could you call those C functions from your C++ function?  I'd look around, wouldn't be surprised if there weren't a C++ wrapper to give similar semantics, or one could be written easily enough.