# Encoding a C style array of ints

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on serializing a class that supports NSCoding.  I've setup `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder`, and all the standard Objective C data types work fine.

What I'm struggling with is how to encode a few simple C arrays.  For example:

```
int bonusGrid[5];
int scoreGrid[10][10];
int solutionGrid[10][10];
int tileGrid[10][10];
```

Short of breaking them up and encoding each int one-by-one, I'm not sure how to deal with them.  Is there a "standard" way to handle C arrays?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you be using the data on other computers? Will there be endian issues?

Comment: iPhone and iPad only.  Maybe Mac someday, but that's not a certainty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to use NSData to wrap the arrays.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)bonusGrid length:5*sizeof(int)] forKey:@"bonusGrid"];
    [coder encodeObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)scoreGrid length:10*10*sizeof(int)] forKey:@"scoreGrid"];
    ...
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    if((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        NSData *data = [coder objectForKey:@"bonusGrid"];
        int *temporary = (int*)[data bytes];
        for(unsigned char i = 0; i < 5; ++i) bonusGrid[i] = temporary[i];
        data = [coder objectForKey:@"scoreGrid"];
        temporary = (int*)[data bytes];
        for(unsigned char i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            for(unsigned char j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
                scoreGrid[i][j] = temporary[i*10 + j];
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

You could also use `memcpy()` to move the data back into your arrays, but it is not proper and not guaranteed to work on all systems (it does work on the iPhone and mac).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm curious why you're using the temporary array when retrieving the bonusGrid instead of just using bonusGrid itself?

Comment: bonusGrid is an array, but the bytes method returns a pointer (which will be freed when the NSData object is released). Trying to assign a pointer to an array is illegal and will cause either a warning or error (I don't remember which, but I think it is an error). You need to copy the contents of the pointer to the location of the array.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yours is the approach I'll probably take.  Seems a shame there's no easier way to go about this.  Apple provides a way to handle native C types, but not arrays of those types?  That's an oversight in my book.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011711/nsarray-to-c-array) question. It details what you would need to do to convert the C array to an `NSArray` object.

Comment: I thought about this approach.  It seems like it might be time intensive though.  We're not talking about a ton of data, but looping through each value, creating an NSNumber, adding it to a NSMutableArray -- it seems like a lot of work.