# NSMutableArray to byte array to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad app which communicates with a webservice. There I can download an encrypted file. In a particular request I get a json with login credentials. Also in that json is a key which is used to encrypt the data.

The key looks like:
[0,44,215,1,215,88,94,150]

With the json framework I can put this key into an NSMutableArray. After that I use a AES256 code to decrypt the file. But that code needs a NSString as a key. So my question is: how can I decode that NSMutableArray into an NSString? I guess I first need to put it into an byte arary, and then put it into an NSString?

Who can help me with this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What encoding are the key bytes given as in the JSON response? UTF8?

Comment: Yes if I'm correct it's UTF8. We use System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged in C# to encode the file, and if I'm correct, it uses UTF8

Comment: Is that what the actual key looks like? If so, then that isn't UTF-8 and if it *starts* with a null character then you're not going to get very far with `NSString`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, convert your array of numbers (I assume they're given as `NSNumbers`) into a C array using code similar to the first snippet in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011711/nsarray-to-c-array). In other words, something similar to this:

```
// Test array for now -- this data will come from JSON response
NSArray* nsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithChar:1],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithChar:2],
                                             nil];
char cArray[2];

// Fill C-array with ints
int count = [nsArray count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    cArray[i] = [[nsArray objectAtIndex:i] charValue];
}
```

Then create an NSString using the correct encoding:

```
NSString *encodedStr = [NSString stringWithCString:cArray encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Note: these are code sketches, they haven't been tested!

**EDIT:** changed from ints to chars.

Comment: `stringWithCString:` will expect a `char *`, not an `int *`, plus, all of the data will be misaligned for UTF-8 interpretation.

Comment: Correct, I've changed the code to use chars. It's still only a sketch, final solution will require some wrangling.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is the sequence of numbers, you can loop through it

```
//Assume you have created keyArray from your JSON
NSMutableString * keyString = [NSMutableString string];
for (id element in keyArray) {
    [string appendFormat:@"%@", id];
}

// if you need the comma's in the string
NSMutableString * keyString = [NSMutableString string];
for (id element in keyArray) {
    [string appendFormat:@"%@,", id];
}
int length = [string length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length-1);
string = [string substringWithRange:range];
```

Comment: No I don't need a string with numbers, I need a decrypted string. The numbers is an array, also called a byte array, which represents some string value. With the solution you give me I just get the string like 0,44,215,1,215,88,94,150 but I need a string like 'mydecodedstring'

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just don't understand your question. It is clear to me now that my suggestion puts you right back where you started.  I was focusing on "how can I decode that NSMutableArray into an NSString?" What NSMutableArray are you trying to decode into a string?  I would imagine your solution is going to take a form similar to mine. Looping through an array, and doing some decoding in the array, appending the decoded results to your final decoded string

Comment: Well the array is just some byte array, so I need the string of that byte array. Decoding those bytes will result in an string

Comment: You can still use Maudicus' first sample, but switch `%@` to `%c` and take the intValue on id. That is, assuming your key array supplies byte values?